# Save checkbox state onclick with phonegap using JS

Tags: cordova, checkbox

I have a bunch of standard html checkboxes, and would like to store them to localStorage when they are clicked, via JS. Could anyone please help me getting started on that?

One method I can think of is to scan all the checkboxes (about 50 checkboxes) whenever a touchstart is detected. However, that seems to be a overkill and may be really slow.

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: R u using Jquery/Javascript ???

Comment: @DiveshSalian JS. Sorry I should've specified that... It's edited now! Thanks for the catch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using jquery u can write a single click event for all the checkbox and u can then search for the id which is checked here is the code and working [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/KcxHb/2/)

Html

```
<label for="chk1">
    <input type="checkbox" name="tester" id="chk1" value="Test1">1</label>
<label for="chk2">
    <input type="checkbox" name="tester" id="chk2" value="Test2">2</label>
```

Jquery Code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(":checkbox").click(function () {
        var thisVar = $(this);
        var id = thisVar.attr('id');
        var isChecked = thisVar.is(':checked');
        alert("id" + id + "   " + "Checked " + isChecked);
        //code to store it on local storage

    });
});
```